# Show only main part of Tikz diagram and outliers via extension

Tags: tikz-pgf

My diagram is too big.

[image: As is]

1. The problem is the red line, which is going below 50.

In some old books I found a nice work around for this. Their the area between the main part and the outlier is left out, and replaced with a zickzack line dividing the diagram.
Can someone help me doing something like that? Maybe it is even possible to show the outlier in a magnifying glass like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49251/how-to-draw-something-only-in-the-magnified-area-tikz-spy-library)!

2. My second problem is the x-scale which should be higher, below the last point at ~20.

My code so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6, xscale=0.65, yscale=0.25]
    % grid
    \draw[gray!40, thin, step=5, dotted] (0,50) grid (24,115); % Grid
    % axis
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (25,0);
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,116);
    % scale
    \foreach \x in {0,2,...,24} \draw (\x,0.05) -- (\x,-0.05) node[below] {\tiny\x};
    \foreach \y in {0,10,...,115} \draw (-0.05,\y) -- (0.05,\y) node[left] {\tiny\y};
    % lines
    \draw[blue!80!black,opacity=0.6, dashed]  (1,76.11) -- (2,114.29) -- (3,62.73) -- (4,65.75) -- (5,79.09) -- (6,76.11) -- (7,95.62) -- (8,93.83) -- (9,74.9) -- (10,85.81) -- (11,93.7) -- (12,79.75) -- (13,79.14) -- (14,87.52) -- (15,83.71) -- (16,76.74) -- (17,85.76) -- (18,81.35) -- (19,69.59) -- (20,81.74) -- (21,68.7) -- (22,74.21) -- (23,70.17) -- (24,83.33);
    \draw[red!80!black] (1,55.56) -- (2,76.02) -- (3,87.25) -- (4,96.97) -- (5,90.28) -- (6,88.64) -- (7,78.28) -- (8,80.39) -- (9,77.01) -- (10,78.13) -- (11,80.91) -- (12,85.42) -- (13,74.55) -- (14,79.91) -- (15,78.78) -- (16,77.31) -- (17,84.75) -- (18,95.84) -- (19,83.94) -- (20,86.79) -- (21,76.44) -- (22,47.76) -- (23,66.06) -- (24,24.06); 
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

By the way, I really had fun drawing the picture! Be happy as well :)

Comment: For plots I woudl highly recommend you use `pgfplots` instead of doing them directly in `tikz`.  Also, please convert your code snippet into a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.  While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: Hm .. so how does this work with pgfplots? I use http://www.tikzedt.org/ to "draw" my graph, thats why there was no documentclass. Is there something similar for pgfplots? What is the "relevant" command in pgfplots to solve this problem?

Comment: For what it's worth, cutting out part of the axis is considered to be bad presentation in many cases. It distorts the relative magnitudes of the different points on your graph, so e.g. it could make the difference between 75 and 80 look much more significant than it really is. But whether this is the case with your graph depends on the interpretation of your data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the same figure with `pgfplots`. Doesn't seem to need to have an interrupted axis:

[image]

or with `axis y discontinuity`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line= bottom,
    axis y line= left,
    ymin = 15,
    ]
\addplot [blue!80!black,opacity=0.6, dashed, ultra thick] coordinates {
    (1,76.11)  (2,114.29)  (3,62.73)   (4,65.75)   (5,79.09)  
    (6,76.11)  (7,95.62)   (8,93.83)   (9,74.9)    (10,85.81)  
    (11,93.7)  (12,79.75)  (13,79.14)  (14,87.52)  (15,83.71)  
    (16,76.74) (17,85.76)  (18,81.35)  (19,69.59)  (20,81.74)  
    (21,68.7)  (22,74.21)  (23,70.17)  (24,83.33)
    };

\addplot [red!80!black, ultra thick] coordinates {
    (1,55.56)  (2,76.02)  (3,87.25)   (4,96.97)   (5,90.28)   
    (6,88.64)  (7,78.28)  (8,80.39)   (9,77.01)   (10,78.13)  
    (11,80.91) (12,85.42) (13,74.55)  (14,79.91)  (15,78.78)  
    (16,77.31) (17,84.75) (18,95.84)  (19,83.94)  (20,86.79)  
    (21,76.44) (22,47.76) (23,66.06)  (24,24.06)
    }; 

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

### Code: `axis y discontinuity`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line= bottom,
    axis y line= left,
    height=10cm, 
    ymax=120,
    xmin=0,
    axis y discontinuity=crunch,% or "parallel"
    extra tick style={major tick length=4pt}
    ]
\addplot [blue!80!black,opacity=0.6, dashed, ultra thick] coordinates {
    (1,76.11)  (2,114.29)  (3,62.73)   (4,65.75)   (5,79.09)  
    (6,76.11)  (7,95.62)   (8,93.83)   (9,74.9)    (10,85.81)  
    (11,93.7)  (12,79.75)  (13,79.14)  (14,87.52)  (15,83.71)  
    (16,76.74) (17,85.76)  (18,81.35)  (19,69.59)  (20,81.74)  
    (21,68.7)  (22,74.21)  (23,70.17)  (24,83.33)
    };

\addplot [red!80!black, ultra thick] coordinates {
    (1,55.56)  (2,76.02)  (3,87.25)   (4,96.97)   (5,90.28)   
    (6,88.64)  (7,78.28)  (8,80.39)   (9,77.01)   (10,78.13)  
    (11,80.91) (12,85.42) (13,74.55)  (14,79.91)  (15,78.78)  
    (16,77.31) (17,84.75) (18,95.84)  (19,83.94)  (20,86.79)  
    (21,76.44) (22,47.76) (23,66.06)  (24,24.06)
    }; 

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks really nice thanks! Is it also possible to do it without adjusting the scale? I still would love to have the zickzack :)

Comment: See revised solution.

Comment: Very nice answer. Thanks. I have a question here. When we use discontinuity in plots, the discontinuity fills the space between y=0 and y=40. We have discontinuity sign and 40 on your plot, but I can not see zero shown on it. Even in x-axis we don't see the discontinuity sign. Is my thought correct or you are showing the correct and standard plotting in this case?

Comment: @PeterGrill thank you, amazing! That was exactly what I wanted!

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent: Have updated the solution to show the x=0 position.