# How I can draw with tikz package this picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf

The idea is to do zoom on the intersections (transparent and dashed disks)

[image]

All the best!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Can you show us what you already tried?

Comment: I am sorry, but I downvoted because you showed no effort.  Nonetheless, welcome to the site.  Perhaps see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that on how to improve your questions in the future.

Comment: The tikz library spy could do the job. - Some insperations:[Spy library examples](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/spy-library/), [How to exclude items from a TikZ Spy](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296276/how-to-exclude-items-from-a-tikz-spy)

Answer (score 5):

You will see that it is way much more fun to do these things yourself.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[very thick] (0,0) circle(2);
\draw[thick] (-3,0) -- (5,0) (0,-3) -- (0,5);
\draw[very thick] (4,-1) -- (2.5,5) coordinate[pos=0.75] (aux);
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\node[circle,draw,fill=gray!50,on background layer,minimum size=1cm] (c1) at (45:2){};
\node[circle,draw,fill=gray!50,on background layer,minimum size=1cm] (c2) at (aux){};
\end{scope}
\draw[very thick] (-0.3,3) node[circle,draw,fill=white,inner sep=3pt]{}
to[bend left] coordinate[midway] (x1) ++ (50:1.5)node[circle,draw,fill=white,inner sep=3pt]{};
\draw[very thick] (5,3) node[circle,draw,fill=white,inner sep=3pt]{}
to coordinate[midway] (x2) ++ (120:1.5)node[circle,draw,fill=white,inner sep=3pt]{};
\foreach \X in {1,2}
{\path (c\X) -- (x\X) coordinate[pos=0.1] (y\X) coordinate[pos=0.7] (z\X); 
\draw[->] (y\X) -- (z\X);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]